# Is there a way to read the "private Node root" variable from class Pattern?

Tags: java, reflection, private, encapsulation

I want to write a parser for regex, and it would be an easy task, if i could use the tree from Pattern class.

I tried to use reflection like this:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("example+");
        Field field_pattern = Pattern.class.getDeclaredField("root");
        field_pattern.setAccessible(true);
        Node fieldValue = (Node) field_pattern.get(pattern);
        
    }

}
```

but it fails when on

```
field_pattern.setAccessible(true);
```

with InaccessibleObjectException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field transient java.util.regex.Pattern$Node java.util.regex.Pattern.root accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util.regex" to unnamed module @27d6c5e0
```

Then I tried to use command line arguments:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.util.regex=ALL-UNNAMED
```

(https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-07/inaccessibleobjectexception/#gsc.tab=0)

but it didn't help.

Comment: Please describe how exactly you use `--add-opens` argument, because this method works for me. The next error that you face looks like this: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.regex.Pattern$BnM cannot be cast to class org.w3c.dom.Node

Comment: Im not sure how i should answer comments, so ill write here, for '--add-opens' i used launch parameters in Intellij idea.

Comment: @Barsikspit you may use an `@` sign with an username to answer comment for particular user. Such an `@Barsikspit` which i used for this comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for '--add-opens' i used launch parameters in Intellij idea.

I suspected that the problem is that you are incorrectly using your  great IDE. This received confirmation in your comment.

You can easily get confused in IDEA's `Run/Debug configuration` window. Yours `--add-opens java.base/java.util.regex=ALL-UNNAMED` parameter is NOT a parameter for your application, which will be passed in `String[] args` of `main` method. It's a parameter of Java Virtual Machine. You must convey this parameter string not to your program, but to JVM.

[image]

You must choose `Add VM options` in `Add run options` menu